# FirebaseCore.h file not generating in project using CocoaPods

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I recently installed CocoaPods and Firebase into my project.  I've been attempting to build but am getting the following errors:

> 1. 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found
> 2. Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'
> 3. Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

I checked my folders and the FirebaseCore.h file definitely does NOT exist. I've reinstalled CocoaPods, modified the Podfile and did a 'pod update' and 'pod install' several times.

I've reviewed several of the questions and solutions listed on stack overflow but none of them have worked.

**Here are my specs:**

1. Xcode 11.3.1
2. Swift 5

**My Podfile looks like this:**

```
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'project' do

      use_frameworks!

      # Pods for Project
      pod 'MessageKit', '~> 3.0.0-swift5'
      pod 'MessageInputBar'
      # Add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

    # Add the pods for any other Firebase products you want to use in your app
    # For example, to use Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
    end
```

Comment: Note that you don't need Firebase/Core any longer as it's included in Analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Somehow my base project had other issues that were generating this error that I was never able to uncover.  So I did the following:
1. Created a new project and imported old project files.
2. Installed cocoapods on the new project
3. Followed the FireBase instructions referenced in the answer from @Jay
4. Cleaned project and performed a build
5. No more error
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the error you'll get when opening the project using the .xcodeproj file.

You need to use the .xcworkspace file to open the project.

That file is generated when installing the pods using cocoapods.

Other things to try

- Quit XCode. Go into terminal and do this `sudo gem install cocoapods`. Then use the cocoapods.app to update the project with your pod file. Then clean and rebuild the project.
- In your project, select the project name in the left column (where the project files are). Then in Targets, ensure the Team popup is selected to your team name, not 'None' and that your Signing Certificate is correct.
- This one is extreme but I have seen it correct some build issues. Deleting the login keychain (using the keychain.app). This will also delete all of your stored passwords so keep that in mind.

Comment: I am using my .xcworkspace file.  I haven't opened my .xcodeproj file since installing cocoapods

Comment: Thank you for responding @Jay, any other recommendations

Comment: @techgirl I ran though the Firebase Guide [Installing for iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) just now and it worked perfectly, so that tells me either a step was missed or there's something else in your project causing the issue. I see in your question the podfile doesn't match that guide so perhaps something was overlooked. I would suggest removing your pods using the cocoapods app. Adjusting you podfile to match exactly and then installing again. From there, ensure you've added the .plist file, and that your developer credentials are up-to-date and selected in the app.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I've gone through the installation guide several times so I believe you're right that something else must be wrong.  I'm going to go through the steps you recommended here...stay tuned.

Comment: I've removed cocoapods and went back through the firebase steps but am still getting the same error as above.

Comment: @techgirl I added a few suggestions to my answer. Also, update your question with your current podfile and I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had same issue when upgrading to Xcode 11.2.1. Errors were resolved after using Firebase 6.13.0. 
Please make changes to your Podfile as below,

```
 pod 'Firebase', '=6.13.0'
 pod 'Firebase/Core'
 pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
```

Comment: thanks for responding. I made the recommended changes but am still getting the two errors. Any other suggestions? Fingers crossed.

Comment: Can you please paste here entire Podfile and error you are getting.

Comment: I've updated the question with the entire pod file 
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.3'

target 'xxxx' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for xxxxxx
  pod 'MessageKit', '~> 3.0.0-swift5'
  pod 'MessageInputBar'
  pod 'Firebase', '=6.13.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

end